# My app is showing install size instead of download size in App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My uploaded iOS app is showing 28.3 MB size in the App Store app on an iPhone 5s. As per the Estimated App Store file size from iTunes Connect, my app size will be as shown in the image.

[image]

My concern is that it is showing the install size (28.4 MB, the amount of disk space that the app will take on the customer's device) in the App Store app on the iPhone 5s.

I think it should be Download Size instead of Install Size. Is anything wrong with the size showing in the App Store? Or is it so?

Comment: What are you asking? It's unclear.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson: edited.

Comment: It's just how Apple wants to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The App Store shows the install size because this is the amount of storage space the user requires on the device once the app is installed. The download size is rarely useful. There is nothing you can do to change what is shown on the App Store page.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to download size for different device is variant . So before build for appstore check that you are build for universal ipa.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the discrepancy between the values. OP is looking at a physical iPhone 5s and the iPhone 5s row in iTunes Connect — the same device.